# Array operation on hive collect_set

Tags: sql, arrays, hadoop, hive, set

I am working on hive on large dataset, I have table with colum array and the content of the colum is as follows.

```
["20190302Prod4"
"20190303Prod1"
"20190303Prod4"
"20190304Prod4"
"20190305Prod3"
"20190307Prod4"
"20190308Prod4"
"20190309Prod4"
"20190310Prod2"
"20190311Prod1"
"20190311Prod4"
"20190312Prod1"
"20190312Prod4"
"20190313Prod2"
"20190313Prod1"
"20190313Prod4"
"20190314Prod4"
"20190315Prod4"
"20190316Prod4"
"20190317Prod1"
"20190317Prod4"]
```

I need a set as per the asc date of prod e.g. I need to trim date from the `array` and apply `collect_set` to get below result.

```
["Prod4",
"Prod1",
"Prod3",
"Prod2"]
```

Comment: Please follow the guidelines on how to ask questions. You should show us how the table looks like, what is expected output and what have you tried. There is no way we can help with the details you've here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode array, remove date (digits at the beginning of the string), aggregate using `collect_set`:

```
with mydata as (--use your table instead of this
select array(
"20190302Prod4",
"20190303Prod1",
"20190303Prod4",
"20190304Prod4",
"20190305Prod3",
"20190307Prod4",
"20190308Prod4",
"20190309Prod4",
"20190310Prod2",
"20190311Prod1",
"20190311Prod4",
"20190312Prod1",
"20190312Prod4",
"20190313Prod2",
"20190313Prod1",
"20190313Prod4",
"20190314Prod4",
"20190315Prod4",
"20190316Prod4",
"20190317Prod1",
"20190317Prod4"
) myarray
)

select collect_set(regexp_extract(elem,'^\\d*(.*?)$',1)) col_name 
  from mydata a --Use your table instead  
       lateral view outer explode(myarray) s as elem;
```

Result:

```
col_name    
["Prod4","Prod1","Prod3","Prod2"]
```

One more possible method is to concatenate array first, remove dates from the string, split to get an array. Unfortunately we still need to explode to do collect_set to remove duplicates (example using the same WITH mydata CTE):

```
select collect_set(elem) col_name        
  from mydata a --Use your table instead 
       lateral view outer explode(split(regexp_replace(concat_ws(',',myarray),'(^|,)\\d{8}','$1'),',')) s as elem
;
```

Comment: thank you it is working , how to do the same processing for multiple array columns?

Comment: @nilesh1212 please ask one more question and provide an example. The solution may be completely different.

Comment: yes I will raise one for that thanks again for your help.